# Redux-form is really good? Doesn't it re-render all page in the case when we use react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-form

I got a question while working with React-redux/redux-form.
I build SPA using React-Router.
React-router uses redux as you know.
What I want to know is the render-flow when you change redux-form-field.
1. user inputs text in redux form field
2. redux form updates redux store
3. Then, all components connected with store are re-rendered.
(It means that all page is refreshed in my case, because I use react-router)
React uses virtual-dom, so twinkles can't be notified.
I'm sorry that I can't express my thinking due to lack of English.
I look forward to hearing your opinions

Comment: What are twinkles?

Comment: well... I mean that page is refreshed frequently.

Comment: I personally suggest use form from `react-bootrstrap` its easy and straight forward to give custom validation

Comment: I admit that redux form is the useful library and many programmers use it. I want to clear my question. Would you like to let me know if I think right?